# bell turbo stick is not connected to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i have bell turbo stick which is not able to connect to Ubuntu 14.04. is there any way to connect it and access internet through it.

Answer (score 0):

please review this guide http://www.westernwillow.com/cms/blog/franco/making-bell-turbo-stick-work-ubuntu by Franco Nogarin to make it work in Ubuntu.